# Netlogo: Replace NaN in a string variable

Tags: netlogo, nan

I have a patch variable made of different possible strings imported from a shp file. In some cases, it contains a `NaN` value that I want to replace with another string. If the variable was of numbers, I could use:

```
ifelse (value <= 0) or (value >= 0)
```

to identify a `NaN`, but in this case it is a string. Any ideas? Thanks

Javier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason:

```
if value = "NaN"
```

won't work?

The `is-number?` and `is-string?` reporters may be useful to you as well.

Comment: "NaN" does not work because as it is written, its a string. I want to identify everything that is not a string (a NaN value) and replace it with a specific string.